# Filling out 2D array based on one or the other argument

Tags: php, arrays

I am downloading from my database people working for different companies and I want to create associative array with values "source" and "target" which represent company IDs that the employee works for. There are at least 2 rows for the same person from my query so I know that each person from my query works at least for 2 companies.

Example if 'Aberdeen asset management plc' works for 'New India Investment Trust PLC' (Company ID 300) and for 'Aberdeen New Dawn Investment Trust PLC' (Company ID 4), I would want to have a row in my array like:

```
"source"=>300,"target"=>4,"officers"=>'Aberdeen asset management plc'
```

Source & Target are interchangable the order does not matter. Each employee could have multiple rows added if he works for more than 2 companies. The only issue occurs when employee works for odd number of companies but then target/source could be set to the previous source/target that this person works for.

Data example:
[image]

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($dataDB)){
    array_push($data, array("Company_ID"=>intval($row['Company_ID']),"Company_Name"=>$row['Company_Name'],"Company_Index"=>$row['Company_Index'], "Officer_Name"=>$row['Officer_Name'], "Officer_Role"=>$row['Officer_Role']));
}
$edges = array();
foreach($data as $d){
    array_push($edges, array("source"=>$d['Company_ID']),"target"=>'',"officers"=>array($d['Officer_Name'])));
}
```

SQL Query is quite long since it is taking into consideration that employees are still working not resigned and taking only workers that work for more than 1 company:

```
SELECT 
    CD.Company_ID,
    CD.Company_Name,
    CD.Company_Index,
    OD.Officer_Name,
    CO.Officer_Role
FROM
    Company_Details CD
INNER JOIN Company_Officer CO 
   ON CD.Company_ID = CO.Company_ID
INNER JOIN Officer_Details OD 
   ON CO.Officer_ID = OD.Officer_ID
WHERE CD.Company_Index<>'' AND 
      CO.Resigned_On='' AND
      CO.Officer_ID IN
       ( SELECT CO2.officer_id
         FROM   Company_Officer CO2
         INNER JOIN Company_Details CD2
         ON CO2.Company_ID = CD2.Company_ID
         WHERE CO2.Resigned_On='' AND CD2.Company_Index<>''
         GROUP  BY CO2.officer_id
         HAVING Count( DISTINCT CO2.company_id ) > 1 
       )
ORDER BY `OD`.`Officer_Name` ASC;
```

Comment: What is your `SQL Query`? Are you retrieving whole table?

Comment: @Vuldo I have added sql query